# Edit Exif Data on UIImage before posting to backend

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiimage, exif

## Problem

I'm posting images to a server, but when I pull them back to the device, they turn sideways.

My thoughts are the Exif data attached to the image are telling the server how to orient the image.

How can I edit the exif data on a UIImage from the camera or library before its sent?  I've seen solutions where they rotate the image when its returned but I want a solution for before its even posted.

A clue to what might be happening is that when the imageOrientation is posted it is normal, but return Up from the server no matter what.  Does this possibly mean that the server is stripping the Exif data needed to determine the orientation?

Thank you.